# Анализатор кода

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, анализ

Необходима библиотека или программа или утилита или что-то типа того, чтобы можно было определить, имея исходный код программы, какие методы (функции и процедуры) использует этот исходный файл кода. Кроме того, среди них нужно выделить те, которые:

1. реализованы самим программистом
2. НЕ реализованы самим программистом (импортируются из других библиотек или пространств имён)

Исходник может быть написан на:

- C# (платформа .NET)
- C++ (GNU C++ 4.4.0)
- C++ (платформа .NET)
- Pascal (Free Pascal 2.2.4)
- Delphi 7
- Java 1.6

Нужно, чтобы код анализировался (ну или хотя бы находились все методы) и результат записывался в какой-то файл, который потом можно было открыть в своей программе для дальнейшего анализа. Т.е. есть проект, к которому нужно "привентить" эту утилиту или библиотеку или программу.

Есть ли такое вообще? И если нет, то как лучше реализовать механизм парсинга кода самому?

Comment: Для C++ проще скомпилировать, напустить nm на .o и разобрать ее вывод. Для Delphi/Pascal наверное тоже можно покопать в этом направлении.

Функции, реализованные самим программистом будут определены в этих .o

Answer (score 2):

Вы не [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), [напару со вспомогательными инструментами](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#12) ищете, случаем?

Upd: Хотя, наверное, нет, если только частично. Весь спектр языков оно не покроет. Можно, впрочем, для каждого языка-двух по готовому инструменту подобрать и сделать поверх этого обертку.

Comment: Просто шикарный вариант! Спасибо! Но как ещё узнать те методы, которые ВЫЗЫВАЮТСЯ в коде?

Comment: По второй ссылке упомянут `cscope` для C, для остальных языков нужно искать свои решения, увы. Это как раз про «upd» в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [source navigator ng](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net). Инструмент для работы с исходными кодами. Predifined parsers for C/C++/Java/Tcl/php/Cobol/Fortran